# Can I receive messages if I chose to block all messages and searches in my profile?

Tags: support, jobs

I applied for two jobs on careers, but I realized a week later that I did it while my profile was set to "Block all messages and searches."

If the employer sent a message during that week, will I have missed the message completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you'll be fine. Blocked simply means you won't show up in our candidate database when customers do a search.

On another note, if you're looking for work, which is implied since you applied for a job, it would behoove you to unblock your profile.

Comment: Already unblocked. Thanks for the info

Comment: Oh, new word for me "behoove" - one never stop learning, thanks! ;)